# Comparing results of mixed-effects logistic regression with crossed random effects: Stata and R (lme4)

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, stata

I have created a mixed-effects logistic model with crossed random effects for my data in both Stata and R (using lme4). The two models, presented below, have yielded very similar estimates for the coefficients, but it appears my method of calculating standard errors and p-values in R differs from Stata's method. Could anyone shed any light on the discrepancy between these two models?

Stata:

```
.melogit A B i.C D || _all: R.E || F:

Mixed-effects logistic regression               Number of obs      =       553

-----------------------------------------------------------
                      |   No. of       Observations per Group
 Group Variable |   Groups    Minimum    Average    Maximum
----------------+------------------------------------------
         _all |        1        553      553.0        553
            F |       23         14       24.0         40
-----------------------------------------------------------

Integration method:     laplace

                                                Wald chi2(3)       =     29.21
  Log likelihood = -337.64555                     Prob > chi2        =    0.0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  A |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                  B |   .0521762   .0259335     2.01   0.044     .0013474    .1030049
               1.C |  -2.563292   .7732082    -3.32   0.001    -4.078753   -1.047832
                  D |  -4.070081   1.131891    -3.60   0.000    -6.288546   -1.851616
           _cons |   2.693203   1.467959     1.83   0.067    -.1839439    5.570349
 ---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
_all>E                |
           var(_cons)|   .9765646   .3263157                      .5073117    1.879867
---------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
F                        |
           var(_cons)|   .0615515   .0880975                      .0037233    1.017531
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. logistic regression:     chi2(2) =    48.95   Prob > chi2 = 0.0000

Note: LR test is conservative and provided only for reference.
```

R (lme4):

```
> my.glmm = glmer(A ~ B + D + C + (1|E) + (1|F), data = my.data, family = 'binomial')
> my.glmm
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: A ~ B + D + C + (1 | E) + (1 |  
F)
   Data: my.data
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid 
 687.2924  713.1846 -337.6462  675.2924       547 
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Std.Dev.
 E  (Intercept) 0.9876  
 F   (Intercept) 0.2479  
Number of obs: 553, groups:  E, 44; F, 23
Fixed Effects:
       (Intercept)                 B                D                  C  
           2.69337             0.05206            -4.06681            -2.55907  
> coefs <- data.frame(coef(summary(my.glmm)))
> coefs$p.z <- 2 * (1 - pnorm(abs(coefs$t.value)))
Error in abs(coefs$t.value) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> coefs
                   Estimate      Std..Error      z.value     Pr...z..
(Intercept)       2.69337259 2.16447149  1.244356 0.2133686532
B                 0.05206151 0.02424857  2.146992 0.0317938861
D                -4.06681259 2.13085477 -1.908536 0.0563220015
C                -2.55906567 0.74622222 -3.429361 0.0006050034
```

I know that I am using a roundabout way to get z scores and p-values for the coefficients in R, but it would seem that Stata's method must somehow be different. I'm hoping that I've specified the model correctly in both programs. Are there some estimation methods or assumptions that differ between Stata and R for this type of model?

Comment: this is somewhat surprising.  Any chance of a reproducible example?  (For those of us unfamiliar with Stata, can you explain how `_all: R.E || F:` is specifying the model, and that it's really equivalent to `(1|E)+(1|F)`? I don't see an estimated variance for `E` in the Stata output ... ??)

Comment: In stata, to specify a mixed model with crossed random effects, you have two options: _all: R.E || _all: R.F or _all: R.E || F:. Both are equivalent, at least according to the stata documentation. I've confirmed that both specifications have the same output for my data. I believe the _all>E line in the output provides the estimates. As far as a reproducible example, I'm not sure how to do this. I've looked around for a publicly available dataset that would be amenable to logistic regression with crossed random effects, but I haven't found anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There's a famous analysis from McCullagh and Nelder on salamander mating here: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/HGLMMM/html/salamander.html .  Alternately, you could use `lme4::simulate.merMod` to simulate a data set with the desired characteristics.  (You could even take the fitted `lme4` model you have and simulate a new data set with it, although (1) that might be a little bit for easy text-dumping and (2) if the structure and not just the responses of your data are confidential you wouldn't want to do it that way.)